# How to quickly restore a UV map that was distorted by edge/vertex slide?

Tags: uv, edges

I messed up my UV map via vertex slide; some UV map vertices are way offscreen and there's too many for easy retrieval. Is there a way to quickly and retroactively fix a UV map that's been distorted in some way, e.g. by edge slide? I somehow changed the poly count from my reference mesh (so I can't simply transfer object data even though they're visually identical), and it's too many undo steps back to retrieve that way. Thanks!

PS There are duplicate UV map points for a given vertex. Currently, I'm snapping my cursor to each correct vertex, then scaling the offscreen vertex to xyz = 0.

Comment: PS is there a way to permanently enable the "correct UV" option (whatever it was called) on edge/vertex slide in v2.8+ so that I DON'T have to deal with this ever again???

Comment: actually the Correct UVs option in the Operator box is enabled by default

Comment: Whaaa, so it was actually contributing to this mess??? Either way, I need to actually find that option and enable or disable it. o.o

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem exactly but as you were referring to edge slide, UV map and Correct UVs option, I just wanted to precise that the option is enabled by default in the Operator box but you may have disabled it? Also if you are in Edit mode, in the top right, in the Options, you have a Correct Face Attributes that makes sure that when you add topology it doesn't mess the UV map

Comment: I didn't know those options exist. Great that the Options box exists in the top right, but it's small enough to nearly be forgettable. I gotta remember to check that out. Also... dumb question, is the operator box that little one that pops up sometimes when I do something (e.g. create sphere)? I usually reach vertex slide by G+G; I've never seen that box for this function.

Comment: Yes the Operator box is on the bottom left, it allows to bring modifications to the last action or manually tweak parameters, when you slide an edge you'll see that you'll have the Correct UVs option available, it is enabled by default, if you disable it it will stay disabled when you'll slide an edge again

Comment: I see that option now (must not have been paying attention to it before), but an n=1 test didn't show me a mobile UV vertex. It'll probably happen later on when I'm not paying attention to it, so I'll keep an eye out for that checkbox next time things move. Thanks!

Comment: what do you call a n=1 test? If you select an edge in Edit mode, press GG and slide, you'll see the option in the Operator box. The box will disappear as soon as you do a new action

Comment: n=1 means I only tried once (sample size n = 1).